# What is the difference between narrowband and wideband?

Tags: wireless, telecommunications

Im a bit confused between the difference of Narrowband signals and Wideband signals.
Is there a specific value of bandwidth which classifies a signal into Narrowband or Wideband?
What values of bandwidth would be considered as Narrow?

Comment: I think the Wiki articles describing these are answering the question in the first line of the description.

Comment: It usually is function of the number of octaves or decades the useful bandwidth is. More than 1 octave/decade is wideband, less is narrowband.

Comment: What's the context of your question?  E.g., are you asking about [how FM radio signals are classified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_modulation#Modulation_index)?  Are you asking about the relationship between the bandwidth of an electronic signal to the [coherence bandwidth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narrowband) of its channel?  Are you asking in some other context?

Comment: I remember seeing a definition in a textbook. If I can find it I will post it. But when you have a single carrier for audio or voice in the VHF and UHF bands, you can be pretty sure it is narrowband. If the signal spectrum is 50% of the carrier frequency, you can be pretty sure it is broadband.

Answer (score 4):

These are just rough labels that depend on context.  Obviously, a narrowband signal has a narrower bandwidth than a wideband signal in the same context, but that's about all you can tell from that.

This is no different than "big" and "small" in everyday language.  Saying something is big or small without context is meaningless.  A small house, for example, is still a lot bigger than a big coffee cup.

Answer (score 1):

My experience is that "narrowband" usually means "whatever new thing we're switching to that uses less bandwidth", and "wideband" usually means the opposite. Of course the specifics are contextual; but for example, in the context of commercial / amateur FM radio communication, wideband right now means 5kHz deviation / 25 kHz bandwidth, and narrowband means 2.5kHz deviation / 12.5 kHz bandwidth. But in a more historical context, the same terms once referred to 15kHz deviation and 5kHz deviation -- as technology marches on, what was once 'narrow' is now 'wide'!

In the *physics* context, there are more specific definitions: "Frequency modulation can be classified as narrowband if the change in the carrier frequency is about the same as the signal frequency, or as wideband if the change in the carrier frequency is much higher (modulation index > 1) than the signal frequency." (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_modulation) But which signals exactly will be 'narrow' or 'wide' depends on how you quantify "much higher". Modern FM communications are definitely narrowband; commercial FM radio is definitely wideband. Stuff in between is fuzzy.

Comment: But what about broadband vs dial up or ISDN?

Comment: I believe "broadband" originally refers to the frequency spectrum used on the phone lines for DSL versus dialup. The latter uses just the ordinary audio frequencies; the former uses higher frequencies that aren't normally passed by the phone network, require equipment changes to deal with, don't travel well over long distances, etc.

Comment: I know what it means, my point is that it contradicts your statement that narrowband is used to refer to "whatever new we're switching to"

Comment: But now that I read it again I understood it differently, and probably the way you actually meant it. Nvm me

Answer (score 0):

I've heard the terms used for many things mo to me over the years.

A narrow band signal is either a single tone or a carrier with on a single modulation applied. So it's frequency spectrum is narrow. Like a clock or a some AM signal.

A wide band signal may be modulated at a higher rate (hence a broader spectrum) or have multiple modulation signals applied such as OFDM. Or the sidebands aren't suppressed well.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the background of the definition for these terms (narrowbadn vs. wideband) is the ratio "occupied signal bandwidth - to - available channel or system bandwidth".

For example, to demonstrate the existence of a negative group delay we can send a amplitude-modulated signal through a band-stop network.

This experiment works only under the following restrictions:

- The bandwidth of the modulated signal must be small enough not to exceed the quasi-linear region of the filters phase response. Hence, it must be a "narrow-band signal" which, certainly, is much smaller than the filters bandwidth-

Answer (score 0):

Examine your dataeye, or your Bit Error Rate, as you change the input bandwidth for a receiver.

Many of the sidebands are not needed, *if* you accept sloppy dataeyes. Thus a signal transmitted wideband, with lots of sin(x)/x sideband (USB & LSB) energy,
may be used in a narrowband receiver.

Answer (score 0):

A narrowband signal is one that has a smaller bandwidth than the coherence bandwidth and therefore is subject to flat fading. A wideband signal is one that does not fit into the coherence bandwidth and therefore experiences frequency selective fading. An OFDM symbol is broken down into separate narrowband channels and since they are just single discrete frequencies, they experience a single discrete level of fading each, which can be calculated by using a training symbol and equalised.

Each frequency within the symbol has a specific frequency response for a certain amplitude at that frequency, and there is one amplitude for that frequency per symbol, this takes into account the self interference from the multipath images of that amplitude. This does not however anticipate interference from another symbol, which cannot be equalised because it is dependent on the previous symbol and not directly ascertianable from just the current symbol and the channel frequency response.